How make this text consistently line up?
I'm trying to display a row of data, I want to display the data neatly. I used \t, but using tab is inconsistent:
Current output (roughly):
Location           City                     Price          Rooms   Bathrooms       Carpark         Type              Furnish
Mont-Kiara       Kuala-Lumpur    1000000                   2            2        0         Built-up                  Partly
Cheras   Kuala-Lumpur    310000                  3            2            0        Built-up         Partly

My current code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct data_struct {
    char location[150];
    char city[150];
    long long int prices;
    int rooms;
    int bathroom;
    int carpark;
    char type[150];
    char furnish[150];
} data[5000];

void data_read(FILE *file) {
    char location[150];
    char city[150];
    long long int prices;
    int rooms;
    int bathroom;
    int carpark;
    char type[150];
    char furnish[150];
    
    char header[1000];
    fscanf(file, "%[^\n]\n", header);
    int i = 0;
    while(fscanf(file, "%[^,],%[^,],%lld,%d,%d,%d,%[^,],%[^\n]\n", location, city, &prices, &rooms, &bathroom, &carpark, type, furnish) == 8) {
        strcpy(data[i].location, location);
        strcpy(data[i].city, city);
        data[i].prices = prices;
        data[i].rooms = rooms;
        data[i].bathroom = bathroom;
        data[i].carpark = carpark;
        strcpy(data[i].type, type);
        strcpy(data[i].furnish, furnish);
        i = i + 1;
    }
}

void display_data(int row) {
    printf("Location \t City \t\t Price \t Rooms \t Bathrooms \t Carpark \t Type \t Furnish\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        printf("%s \t %s \t %lld \t %d \t %d \t %d \t %s \t %s\n", data[i].location, data[i].city, data[i].prices, data[i].rooms, data[i].bathroom, data[i].carpark, data[i].type, data[i].furnish);
    }
}

int main() {
    FILE *file = fopen("file(in).csv", "r");
    data_read(file);
        
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);

    display_data(t);
        
    return 0;
}    

I tried looking for a solution for this online, but haven't found anything useful. Is there a way to make it look like this in C?
Expected output would look something like this (without the border):



Location
City
Prices
Rooms
Bathrooms
Carpark
Type
Furnish




Mont-Kiara
Kuala-Lumpur
1000000
2
2
0
Built-up
Partly


Cheras
Kuala-Lumpur
310000
3
2
0
Built-up
Partly




Despite not having the contents of the file you're printing, it's clear that the answer here is to use the width field with the %s format specifier to ensure alignment.
E.g.
printf("%-8s %-8s %-8s\n", "A", "B", "C");
printf("%-8d %-8d %-8d\n", 42, 56, 896);

Prints:
A        B        C
42       56       896

Or perhaps:
printf("%-8s %-8s %-8s\n", "A", "B", "C");
printf("%8d %8d %8d\n", 42, 56, 896);
printf("%8.2f %8.2f %8d\n", 3.14, 9.23454, 7);

A        B        C
      42       56      896
    3.14     9.23        7


@Aleph Notice that the width field is a minimum width. If a string or a number requires more space than the width field reserves, it will still print all and your table will not be  aligned. You may want to add code for handling that.
